# NVIDIA framebuffer single resolution on linux unable to change

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, framebuffer

Disclaimer: Any (and likely) all terms I'm using are wrong or inapropriate to the intended function.

Under /sys/class/graphics/fb0/modes the only resolution available is U:640x480p-73

I have a dumb resolution of 1366x768 monitor and run Arch based Artix Linux with an NVIDIA GT710 graphics card and nvidia-470xx-dkms drivers for it. I'd use Nouveau as I have before, however due to stability and compatibility issues I'm switching back to proprietary drivers.

As far as I understand the problem (likely wrong) at hand is that the proprietary drivers don't supply `fbdev` and would be fixed by installing `uvesafb` which provides `fbdev`, but I can't get the makepkg to clone the repo, using the dev branch won't compile as well as manually compiling after cloning repo just fails

This is how I understand it to work; syslinux enables `efifb`, then loads the linux kernel passing the framebuffer to it, the kernel enables the NVIDIA drivers for Xorg and as `nvidia-470xx-dkms` doesn't suply `fbdev` to manage the framebuffer 'directly'?, there's only one resolution available and listed as `Unknown`

I changed my syslinux.cfg adding `RESOLUTION 1366 768`, rebooting and changing the framebuffer to said resolution successfully

while I now have a reasonable resolution, that still leaves the question of "How can I change the framebuffer resolution after boot" as fbset doesn't and there's only one resolution available

I've read the arch wiki for anything relevant and either I'm mentally deficient or no solutions are applicable

Technically this is a non-issue as I have a reasonable `tty` console resolution. I'd still like the ability to change framebuffer resolutions even if just to better understand how it all works.